# Angular2 routing and intercepting calls (changes in HTTP API somewhere from version 2.1.0 to version 2.2.3.)

Tags: http, angular, version, rxjs, flatmap

(***This question is the result of the changes in the HTTP API somewehere in between versions 2.1.0 and 2.2.3. It may be best to just look at the answer, as the effects of the changes are explained there.***)

Here is the sequence I have:

I intercept a call, ..., refresh a token if needed, and make a second Http call:

```
 intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return observable.catch((err: any, caught: Observable<Response>) => {
       ...
                return this.refreshtoken().flatMap((res) => 
                this.returnLastMethod(returnMethod, returnUrl, returnData));
```

In refreshToken():

```
localStorage.setItem('accessToken', x);
```

In one of the methods inside the returnLastMethod i do a

```
let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
```

and as a result I always get the access token from one Http call before. Now this is a code that worked before switching to Angular ver: 2.2.3, and still does, but obviously I am missing something here as it is not working in Angular-2.2.3.

Here is the Chrome Output:

[image]

That is when I use the private variable to create new headers. For some reason the Http call uses some other value, as if it just repeats the old Http call (in console log is shown that the new value is that what I give to the method).

The code of the function where I give the new value to the second Http call:

```
 private returnLastMethod(typ: number, url: string, data?: any): Observable<Response> {
    let lastMethodOptions = new RequestOptions();
    lastMethodOptions.headers = new Headers();
    let accessToken1 = this.currentAccessToken;
    console.log(accessToken1 + ' - set to Bearer');
    lastMethodOptions.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken1);
    lastMethodOptions.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    switch (typ) {
        case 1:
            console.log('url: ' + url + ' options: ');
            for (let i = 0; i < lastMethodOptions.headers.values().length; i++) { console.log(lastMethodOptions.headers.values()[i]); };
            return super.request(url, lastMethodOptions);
        case 3:
            console.log('url: ' + url + ' options: ');
            for (let i = 0; i < lastMethodOptions.headers.values().length; i++) { console.log(lastMethodOptions.headers.values()[i]); };
            return super.put(url, data, lastMethodOptions);
        case 4:
            console.log('url: ' + url + ' options: ');
            for (let i = 0; i < lastMethodOptions.headers.values().length; i++) { console.log(lastMethodOptions.headers.values()[i]); };
            return super.post(url, data, lastMethodOptions);
        case 5:
            console.log('url: ' + url + ' options: ');
            for (let i = 0; i < lastMethodOptions.headers.values().length; i++) { console.log(lastMethodOptions.headers.values()[i]); };
            return super.delete(url, lastMethodOptions);
        default:
            console.log('url: ' + url + ' options: ');
            for (let i = 0; i < lastMethodOptions.headers.values().length; i++) { console.log(lastMethodOptions.headers.values()[i]); };
            return super.get(url, lastMethodOptions);
    };

}
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. The new Http call should use the new value that is displayed in the console log, but it seems as if it doesn't?

Comment: Could you post the whole stream maybe? From your code I don't see why `refreshToken()` should be executed after `returnLastMethod()`.

Comment: If your log looks fine, then the issue must be somewhere withing the `super.get(...)` is this directly inherited by Angular Http? Or is there some class of your own in between?

Comment: I see it now, in url there is an url['url'] that I should have been using. Do not know why it worked before, but now I need to use this so. Seems url had a field with token as well, and has been using that to make the second call? Anyway, I've used the stripped version with just the url and it works. I have no stamina now to look the content of the url in the previous compiler.
Will now try to see what is with the localstorage, if that updates itself or not, then I'll do an update to the question/answer.
Thanks for your presence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the following. Before switching to Angular-2.2.3, I used functions like the following:

```
    request(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
   ...
    return this.intercept(super.request(url, this.getRequestOptionsArgs(options)));
}
```

This worked, but after switching to Angular-2.2.3, url is not just a string any more, it is an object, and it holds token inside, as well.

When I wanted to make a new request to return the last visited page (with the new headers, and new token), this was not used to make the call. Instead, because I was using the url which had the token inside, this token was used.

After using `url['url']` all problems disappeared.

**Update**

I have done some refactoring, and in the process have found out the following:

In request function is url an object, in the others methods is url the string.

So if you look down:

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response>
```

It says that url can take also the whole request inside, and that is what it does.
In my code, i had something like:

```
    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this.lastMethod = 5;
    this.lastUrl = url;
    return this.intercept(super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionsArgs(options)));
}
```

The similar for get,post,put...

Somehow, after them (get,put,post...) is the request command called, and this command now has the whole request inside itself, and that created problems in my code, as my function was expecting string at this place.
As i repeat, this functioned differently before, probably without the call to request method, as this problem was nonexistent before...

Comment: Useful answer, thanks. When you get a moment, would you 'self-accept' it? To do so, click the tick mark to the left, so that it turns green. This marks it as solved.

Comment: I will, i need to wait 10 more hours.... I have updated the question and answer to reflect the new findings, it was the angular`s package version that broke it.